# laplace equation with inhomogeneous neumann boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, elliptic-operators

I want to prove that if the constant $k>0$ is sufficiently large, then for every $f\in L^2(0,1)$, there exists a unigue $u\in H^2(0,1) $ satisfying
$$-u''+ku=f \; on \;(0,1) $$
$$u'(0)=0,\;\; u'(1)=u(1)$$

for this problem, i want to find appropriate Bilinear form B to satisfy the condition for Lax-Milgram thorem (Similar as Energy estimates so that there is such $k$).

so for $B[u,v]=\int -u''vdx=-u(1)v(1)+\int u'v'dx$ it cannot be bounded by $\alpha ||u||||v||$ for some $\alpha$ since the constant must depend on u,v

and also not sure about the coercivity.

Is there proper bilinear form to satisfy the condition for Lax-Milgram theorem to prove the existence of unique solution u?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case 
$$B(u,v)=-u(1)v(1)+\int\limits_0^1 {u'v' + kuvdx}$$
It is clear that this bilinear form is continuous over $$V = \left\{ {u \in {H^1},u(0) = 0,u'(1) = u(1)} \right\}$$
we can prove that $B$ is continuous by using the embedding of ${H^1}(0,1)$ into ${L^\infty }(0,1)$.

Comment: thank you very much, i have one more question. is there a way to handle k so that this bilinear form satisfies the coercivity condition?

Comment: $B$ has a chance to be coercive if the $k$ is myltiply by $u''$ not with $u$ is the equation.